# Parallelize for loops in Python to speed up the algorithm

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, image-processing, parallel-processing

This algorithm consists of reading all images in a folder ending with clipped.tiff and the for loop, which changes the gamma value of all scanned images, is to be accelerated.

How is it possible to parallelize and speed up this simple algorithm?

```
SinglestreetsFolder = "/dop_shapefile/"
shp_list = [x for x in os.listdir(SinglestreetsFolder) if x.endswith("clipped.tiff")]


for i in range(0, len(shp_list), 1):

    originalPath = "/dop_shapefile/" + shp_list[i]
    original = cv2.imread(originalPath)

    adjusted = adjust_gamma(original, gamma=0.3)

    cv2.imwrite("/gamma/" + shp_list[i] + "_gamma.tiff", adjusted)
    print "status_Gamma: ", i + 1, "/", len(shp_list)
```

---

**Another algorithm**

This algorithm consists of reading all images in a folder ending with .tiff and the for loop, that executes the ConnectedComponentLabeling algorithm (with customizations) to speed up.

```
SinglestreetsFolder = "/gabor/"
shp_list = [x for x in os.listdir(SinglestreetsFolder) if x.endswith(".tiff")]


img = cv2.imread(SinglestreetsFolder + shp_list[0], 0)
wholeimage = np.zeros(shape=(len(img), len(img[0]), 3))
erosion = np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8)     # kernel: erosion

for j in range(0, len(shp_list), 1):
    if "motorway" in shp_list[j]:
        N = 40  # pixel threshold (city: ca. 10, motorway: ca. 40)
    else:
        N = 10   # pixel threshold (city: ca. 10, motorway: ca. 40)

    img = cv2.imread(SinglestreetsFolder + shp_list[j], 0)
    connectivity = 8    # 4- OR 8-connectivity connected component labeling


    if "reverse" in shp_list[j]:
        img = cv2.threshold(img, 140, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]  # ensure binary

        img = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, erosion)

        retval, labels = cv2.connectedComponents(img, connectivity)

        num = labels.max()

        # If the count of pixels less than a threshold, then set pixels to `0` (background)
        for i in range(1, num + 1):
            pts = np.where(labels == i)
            if len(pts[0]) < N:
                labels[pts] = 0

        # Map component labels to hue val
        label_hue = np.uint8(179 * labels / np.max(labels))
        blank_ch = 255 * np.ones_like(labels)
        labeled_img = cv2.merge([blank_ch, blank_ch, blank_ch])

        # set bg label to black
        labeled_img[label_hue == 0] = 0

        wholeimage = np.where(labeled_img == 0, wholeimage, labeled_img)

    else:
        img = cv2.threshold(img, 140, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]  # ensure binary

        retval, labels = cv2.connectedComponents(img, connectivity)

        num = labels.max()

        # If the count of pixels less than a threshold, then set pixels to `0` (background)
        for i in range(1, num + 1):
            pts = np.where(labels == i)
            if len(pts[0]) < N:
                labels[pts] = 0

        # Map component labels to hue val
        label_hue = np.uint8(179 * labels / np.max(labels))
        blank_ch = 255 * np.ones_like(labels)
        labeled_img = cv2.merge([blank_ch, blank_ch, blank_ch])

        # set bg label to black
        labeled_img[label_hue == 0] = 0

        wholeimage = np.where(labeled_img == 0, wholeimage, labeled_img)


    print "status_CCL: ", j + 1, "/", len(shp_list)

cv2.imwrite("/ccl/streets_gabor_ccl.tiff", wholeimage)
```

---

**My solution, but "wholeimage" is black at the end**

```
SinglestreetsFolder = "/gabor/"
shp_list = [x for x in os.listdir(SinglestreetsFolder) if x.endswith(".tiff")]


def gabor(params):
    img = cv2.imread(SinglestreetsFolder + shp_list[0], 0)
    wholeimage = np.zeros(shape=(len(img), len(img[0]), 3))
    erosion = np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8)  # kernel: erosion

    j, image_name = params

    if "motorway" in image_name:
        N = 40  # pixel threshold (city: ca. 10, motorway: ca. 40)
    else:
        N = 10   # pixel threshold (city: ca. 10, motorway: ca. 40)

    img = cv2.imread(SinglestreetsFolder + image_name, 0)
    connectivity = 8    # 4- OR 8-connectivity connected component labeling


    if "reverse" in image_name:
        img = cv2.threshold(img, 140, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]  # ensure binary

        img = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, erosion)
        # img = cv2.erode(img, erosion, iterations=1)

        retval, labels = cv2.connectedComponents(img, connectivity)

        num = labels.max()

        # If the count of pixels less than a threshold, then set pixels to `0` (background)
        for i in range(1, num + 1):
            pts = np.where(labels == i)
            if len(pts[0]) < N:
                labels[pts] = 0

        # Map component labels to hue val
        label_hue = np.uint8(179 * labels / np.max(labels))
        blank_ch = 255 * np.ones_like(labels)
        labeled_img = cv2.merge([blank_ch, blank_ch, blank_ch])

        # set bg label to black
        labeled_img[label_hue == 0] = 0

        wholeimage = np.where(labeled_img == 0, wholeimage, labeled_img)

    else:
        img = cv2.threshold(img, 140, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]  # ensure binary

        retval, labels = cv2.connectedComponents(img, connectivity)

        num = labels.max()

        # If the count of pixels less than a threshold, then set pixels to `0` (background)
        for i in range(1, num + 1):
            pts = np.where(labels == i)
            if len(pts[0]) < N:
                labels[pts] = 0

        # Map component labels to hue val
        label_hue = np.uint8(179 * labels / np.max(labels))
        blank_ch = 255 * np.ones_like(labels)
        labeled_img = cv2.merge([blank_ch, blank_ch, blank_ch])

        # set bg label to black
        labeled_img[label_hue == 0] = 0

        wholeimage = np.where(labeled_img == 0, wholeimage, labeled_img)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool()

    list(p.imap(gabor, enumerate(shp_list)))
    cv2.imwrite(/ccl/streets_gabor_ccl.tiff", wholeimage)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

`Pool` might be useful for your needs, if the actions you want to perform are independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from assumption that `adjust_gamma` doesn't `fork` child processes or uses C threads, image processing is CPU bound process so you should rely on processes and not threads in Python.

Here is how it should look:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

SinglestreetsFolder = "/dop_shapefile/"
shp_list = [x for x in os.listdir(SinglestreetsFolder) if x.endswith("clipped.tiff")]

def process_image(params):
    i, image_name = params
    originalPath = "/dop_shapefile/" + image_name
    original = cv2.imread(originalPath)

    adjusted = adjust_gamma(original, gamma=0.3)

    cv2.imwrite("/gamma/" + image_name + "_gamma.tiff", adjusted)
    return "status_Gamma: ", i + 1, "/", len(shp_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool()
    results = list(p.imap(process_image, enumerate(shp_list)))
    print results
```

There are certain parts that could be changed, I just went to adapt your example with as less changes as I could make.

Comment: could you explain why the use of processes is more appropriate then the use of threads in this example?

Comment: Thumbs up for using multiprocessing. Only this will benefit from multicore systems in this situation.

Comment: When I run your algorithm, "TypeError: process_image() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)" appears

Comment: Threads in Python are constrained by Python's GIL. That way you end up with multiple threads being executed on one CPU core. Multiprocessing gives you option to utilize multiple cores.

Comment: @ikac That's under the assumption that the image processing lib is actually fully implemented in Python and in the process. If the lib creates subprocesses or it is written as a C addon then threads may perform better then processes.

Comment: @ikac Can you please help me with another algorithm, where more input variables are needed?

Comment: @freddykrueger Can you please start with implementation by looking at solution for the first one? First step is to define single unit of work i.e. how would you define function that has to do single image 'processing'. Also, define input arguments. Give it a try and post snippet when you are stuck.

Comment: @freddykrueger `wholeimage` is declared as `global` in `gabor` function. Apart from being discouraged to use `global`, you will end up with separate data in `wholeimage` in each process. Each child process has a copy of all global variables and when you change it, it stores it in its context. Because you do not return `wholeimage` from process, you will not have result in main process.

Comment: @freddykrueger Do you have any `traceback` that shows whats the issue, or everything works fine but result is not correct?

Comment: @ikac The algorithm runs through, but the final image is only black

Comment: @ikac I remove the global variable, but now wholeimage can't be saved

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`threading`-lib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html):

```
import threading

SinglestreetsFolder = "/dop_shapefile/"
shp_list = [x for x in os.listdir(SinglestreetsFolder) if x.endswith("clipped.tiff")]

def wrapper(i):
    originalPath = "/dop_shapefile/" + shp_list[i]
    original = cv2.imread(originalPath)
    adjusted = adjust_gamma(original, gamma=0.3)
    cv2.imwrite("/gamma/" + shp_list[i] + "_gamma.tiff", adjusted)
    print "status_Gamma: ", i + 1, "/", len(shp_list)

threads = []

for i in range(0, len(shp_list), 1):
    t = threading.Thread(target=wrapper, args=(i,))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

for t in threads: 
    t.join() # wait for all of them to finsih
# continue with your code
```

Comment: This code has to start from assumption that `adjust_gamma` is not offloaded to child process or any C thread solution that will be able to utilize multiple CPU cores. Even then, if there are hundreds of images, it creates hundreds of threads, which still can be improved by using threads pool.